# How do I get an object id from JSON format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am using the `Alpha Vantage API` to get stock market data. The data is returned in this format:
[image: Raw Stock Data]

For charting purposes, I need to create an `array` or `object` of all of the dates. They are not within the actual data objects so I'm not sure how to do this.

For example, for this specific data I would want an array that looks something like this:

```
['2021-04-26', '2021-04-26', '2021-04-26', '2021-04-26', '2021-04-26', '2021-05-03'...]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you add a example of json in your post? to make it more easier

Comment: could you provide us a JSON?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

You didn't provide sample json, so this is formatted code and not a snippet.

```js
const dates = Object.keys(data['Time Series (Daily)'])
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed

Comment: Please refrain from answering such obvious duplicates. Instead, find the duplicate and flag the question as such, or, if it's already got a comment starting with "Does this answer your question?" follow the link that comes after that comment, and if the answers answer this question, flag this question.